# C# CodeAnalysis - Structure of expressions

Tags: c#, syntax, roslyn

I want to do a simple code replacement in a C# (.NET 4.5) script in VS2013. Each `@GetIt` call should be rewritten so that it is encapsulated in a lambda function:

```
new MyClass(@GetInt("a") * @GetInt("b"));
```

becomes

```
new MyClass( x => (x.GetInt("a") * x.GetInt("b")) )
```

I installed the CodeAnalysis of Roslyn to parse the scripts. I use the following call to get all tokens with the `@GetInt` identifier:

```
var getters = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText("new MyClass(@GetInt("a") * @GetInt("b"));")
                              .GetRoot().DescendantTokens().OfType<SyntaxToken>()
                              .Where(x => x.Text.Equals("@GetInt"));
```

For `@GetInt` as a simple parameter of the `MyClass` constructor it works fine and using `getters[i].Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent` I correctly get to the `MethodDeclarationSyntax` node of the constructor.

However, adding the multiplication as in the example on the top, token for the second `@GetInt` declares `* GetInt("b")` as its parent (it is howevver already a `MethodDeclarationSyntax`, not a parameter node) and traversing back to its parent leads to the `CompilationUnitSyntax` which is the root!

This way, I get no information about the position of the second `@GetInt` in the syntax tree. Consequently the replacement is not possible without the missing information.

I have checked the case without using the prefix `@`, but the result was the same. Can someone please tell me whether I'm doing something wrong?

**SOLUTION** as suggested by JoshVarty in one of his comments: Until the code analysis of Scripts is disabled in the NuGet package, I have to use a workaround. First, I take the `string script = "..."` and decorate it to

```
var decoratedScript = "class MYCLASS { void METHOD() {\n" + script + "\n} }";
```

After the rewriting of `@GetInt` is done, I remove the added decorations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `ParseText()` expects you to be passing in a typical C# document. (Something comprised of using statements, namespaces, types etc.)

If you'd like to parse individual expressions you can use `CSharpParseOptions` to do so:

```
var parseOptions = CSharpParseOptions.Default;
parseOptions = parseOptions.WithKind(SourceCodeKind.Script); //We're going to be passing individual expressions in.

var getters = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"new MyClass(@GetInt(""a"") * @GetInt(""b""));", parseOptions)
                  .GetRoot().DescendantTokens().OfType<SyntaxToken>()
                  .Where(x => x.Text.Equals("@GetInt"));
```

When I use this, I get both invocations of `@GetInt` as a child of a `BinaryExpressionSyntax` (The multiplication).

You can see the tree was originally parsed incorrectly for yourself via:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"new MyClass(@GetInt(""a"") * @GetInt(""b""));");
var errs = tree.GetDiagnostics().Where(n => n.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error);
```

**Edit** Really sorry, it appears that the scripting APIs were removed for RTM. The only work around I can think of for you to try is to wrap every statement in a class and a method until this starts working again.

The reason it's present on http://sourceroslyn.io is because that's based off the current master and they're re-adding it in.

Comment: There is no `WithKind()` method in the parse options. Can it be that it was not present in 4.5? There is only With: `DocumentationMode()`, `Features()`, `LanguageVersion()`, `PreprocessorSymbols()`. There is a property `Kind`, however with a protected setter.

Comment: Solved by using `var parseOptions = new CSharpParseOptions(LanguageVersion.CSharp6, DocumentationMode.Parse, SourceCodeKind.Script);`

Comment: Is it possible you're using an older version of the NuGet package? I see it available at: http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/CSharpParseOptions.cs,53564a1eb75d023c

Comment: Unfortunately, after calling this constructor, I get a `{Syntax}` `NotSupportedException` exception.

Comment: I use Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.{CSharp, Common, Analyzers} all of Version 1.0.0 by Microsoft.

Comment: It is [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/), published one month ago.

Comment: That's bizarre. Here's a screenshot of the code in action with the 1.0.0 DLLs. https://gyazo.com/8eba1055892d36d3ebad2ea2dc7a5cf4

Comment: Can it be that I'm using VS 2013? I'm sorry that I can't verify your answer, yet I believe it is correct. Thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 with the 1.0.0 DLLs and I also don't see `WithKind()`. @JoshVarty did you find out that the method was removed without changing the assembly version? I think it is related to Roslyn not supporting scripting yet (the support is present in the nightly builds)

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer. I didn't realize they changed the APIs. Unfortunately, they didn't change the version number of the assembly, so it looked like I was on v1.0.0 as well. See: https://gyazo.com/78913d2ee7e2aa32a2fa9351a9e531d9 and https://gyazo.com/5608b313f017ef13939e0a25d6c20b4b